# Validating my understanding of Dismax query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, search-engine, dismax

I have tried understanding how dismax query works and I want to validate my understanding, please see if I understood it correctly.

According to documentation a dismax query is:

> A query that generates the union of documents produced by its
> subqueries, and that scores each document with the maximum score for
> that document as produced by any subquery, plus a tie breaking
> increment for any additional matching subqueries.

Suppose, the total documents in our ES cluster be as follows:
`{"FOO":"ABC"},{"FOO":"XYZ"},{"FOO":"ABC XYZ"},{"FOO":"ABC DEF"},{"FOO":"DEF"}` and the dismax query is:

```
 "dis_max": {
   "queries": [
     {
       "match": {
         "FOO": "ABC"
       }
     },
     {
       "match": {
         "FOO": "XYZ"
       }
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

So, as per the documentation let us first find out union of documents returned by dismax's sub-queries. The union of documents would be `{"FOO":"ABC"},{"FOO":"XYZ"},{"FOO":"ABC XYZ"},{"FOO":"ABC DEF"}`. According to the next step we need to score each document with the maximum score for that document as produced by any subquery. Which will be something like:

`{"FOO":"ABC"}`will be scored on `{"match":{"FOO": "ABC"}}` and `{"match":{"FOO": "XYZ"}}` and the maximum score returned will be used.
And similarly, `{"FOO":"XYZ"}`will be scored on `{"match":{"FOO": "ABC"}}` and `{"match":{"FOO": "XYZ"}}` and the maximum score returned will be used and this will be done for all the union of documents and finally the documents will be returned in a sorted way.

Is this how dismax query works? Or did I misunderstand or miss out anything?

Comment: I think you have it right, the doc `{"FOO":"ABC"}` would take the score from `{"match":{"FOO": "ABC"}}` and ignore the score for `{"match":{"FOO": "XYZ"}}`. I usually see this query used to match across multiple fields, for when you are unsure what the field a user query is aiming for, you can return the best option out of several fields.

Comment: Thanks @Nate, you can add an answer now.

Comment: I think you already had the answer! I don't have anything new to contribute